# How to decide when to run different android applications components in a separate process

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-manifest, android-contentprovider

I have read the following statements [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes)

`By default, all components of the same application run in the same process and most applications should not change this. However, if one needs to control which process a certain component belongs to, he can do so in the manifest file. The manifest entry for each type of component element—<activity>, <service>, <receiver>, and <provider>—supports an android:process attribute that can specify a process in which that component should run. One can set this attribute so that each component runs in its own process or so that some components share a process while others do not.`

**I want to know in which scenarios a developer would like to do so and run different components in different processes and what advantage will he get by doing so?**

Another statement that I have read is

`The <application> element in the manifest file also supports an android:process attribute, to set a default value that applies to all components`

Regarding the above statement I want to know **Why would a developer do that, there is already one process associated with one application by default and all the components run inside that process.**

Can anyone clarify these things for me as I am not getting any details on this anywhere else

thanks

Comment: Care to give us the link you read that at?  I'm wondering if context would make it clearer.

Comment: link added for ur reference @GabeSechan

Answer (score 16):

Let us take the example of `Google Chrome browser` which has made best use of `android:process` attribute. Before that let us understand why multi-process architecture was considered.

Remember those age old days, when we were using co-operative multi-tasking operating system. There was one single process and applications used to run in that single process turn by turn. Problem with that architecture was, if one application misbehaves that single process dies off there by bringing entire system down.

Now a days modern operation system, run applications in their own processes. If one application misbehaves, the process hosting it dies off and does not affect rest of the system.

Same applies to the browser. If one web-page misbehaves, it brings down the entire browser there by making web-pages opened in other tabs unavailable. Hence multi-process architecture was built.

Separate processes are used for browser tabs to protect the browser application from bugs in the rendering engine. Each render process is run as an android service in separate process. This is done by using `android:process` tag of `<service>` element. Another important flag used for rendering engine process is [android:isolateProcess](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#isolated). This flag ensures render process does not have access to the system resources like network, display and file system, there by making the browser application highly secure.

Here is the snippet of chrome's manifest file:

```
 <service android:name="org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0" android:permission="com.google.android.apps.chrome.permission.CHILD_SERVICE" android:exported="false" android:process=":sandboxed_process0" android:isolatedProcess="true" />
```

Here is the output of adb shell:

```
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
u0_a14    12926 317   694380 102828 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.chrome
u0_i16    26875 317   590860 59012 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process5
u0_i17    27004 317   577460 47644 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process6
```

> The  element in the manifest file also supports an
>   android:process attribute, to set a default value that applies to all
>   components

By default the name of the application process will be the package name specified in `<manifest>` tag. This can be overridden by specifying the name in the `android:process` attribute of the `<application>` tag. One use case : if multiple applications want to run in the same process, provided those applications are signed by same certificate and share the user ID.

If the name of `<android:process>` starts with `:`, it becomes private to that application, as in case of chrome's rendering engine (`com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process5`). It implies  applications except `com.android.chrome` cannot communicate with this rendering engine.

If the name of `<android:process>` starts with lowercase character, it becomes global process. From [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#proc):

> This allows components in different applications to share a process,
>   reducing resource usage.

**Summary of benefits:**

- To improve overall application stability (crashes / hangs). One service process crash does not bring down entire application.
- Security by preventing access to the rest of the system.
- Reduce resource usage, by running component in a process and sharing it among different applications.

Basically you should be able to separate the concerns and decide whether it makes sense to apply multi-process architecture.

**Update 1**: Adding @Budius comment

Each process have only a certain amount of memory available. In the app I work at, we do computational intensive processing in large memory arrays. Those computational we always fire in a separate process to make sure we'll have enough memory for the whole thing to happen and not crash with OutOfMemory.

Comment: I would add it to your answer memory constrains as well. Each process have only a certain amount of memory available. In the app I work at, we do computational intensive processing in large memory arrays. Those computational we always fire in a separate process to make sure we'll have enough memory for the whole thing to happen and not crash with OutOfMemory.

Comment: @Budius Thanks for sharing valuable information. If it is ok with you, can I append your comment to the answer, giving you the credit.

Comment: @Budius: You could use a largeHeap for that.

Comment: @ManishMulimani: good answer. Anyway, I don't get fully the first point: what would be the advantage to span multiple services instead of having one service with a thread pool and an appropriate exception handlers? And for the third point, do you have any practical example? I definitely see some value here, but I cannot picture a concrete scenario

Comment: @Gil it's an app on Google Play with 700 thousand active users. Those users devices range from the latest flagships all the way down to Samsung disposable crapware and super cheap supermarket branded devices. Just large heap unfortunately is not enough. Even in a new process with large heap we still have to `try{} catch(OutOfMemory){}` to avoid crashing.

Comment: @Budius: ahah crazy :)

Comment: @Gil For the first point, i added one more statement. WRT to chrome, What I meant is one malformed html does not bring down entire browser app. Only that specific tab displaying the html file becomes unresponsive or crashes. Regarding 3rd point, I haven't come across any practical example. Efforts are on to find one.

Comment: @ManishMulimani: regarding the 1st point, I understood what you say, but what is the advantage of your multiple process approach over rendering each page in one thread in a thread pool, handling eventual crashes with exception handlers?

Comment: @ManishMulimani: hmm depends I guess. The whole idea of process killing is that the system tries to kill processes that are not important for the user, I don't think it has an idea of a wasteful process (I might be wrong here). So if the javascript code is hanging but still relevant to the user then it won't be killed. Anyhow, I'm thinking that it can be a way to organize a big app: Chrome probably uses multiple threads for the rendering, say a couple for the images, one for text etc... Coordinating this across multiple pages in a thread pool would be a mess

Comment: @Gil One extreme scenario, consider a javascript function with infinite loop. The process executing the javascript function will eventually become unresponsive and will be killed. Now a days web pages are not just static pages, they are infact applications. A not well written application can bring entire system down, if all execute in same process. Here browser is equivalent to android system, both run multiple applications and should protect each from other.

Comment: @Gil You can go through the [chrome architecture docs](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture) and also I've worked on Android chrome application. That is the reason I gave this example.

Answer (score 2):

The reason one might want to do this is because Android can shut down your application process to free up memory in the system any time it wants to, and you may want to mitigate the situation.

Suppose you have a really, really important piece of code that takes a long while to complete that would be very bad to kill in the middle of it working (for instance, a financial transaction in bank software). Putting this piece of code in a `Service` that runs in a separate **process** from the rest of the application code will ensure Android doesn't kill your `Service` that is potentially still running after the user exited your application.

From the docs:

> When deciding which processes to kill, the Android system weighs their
>   relative importance to the user. For example, it more readily shuts
>   down a process hosting activities that are no longer visible on
>   screen, compared to a process hosting visible activities. The decision
>   whether to terminate a process, therefore, depends on the state of the
>   components running in that process.

You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Answer (score 1):

In general, a `Service` is used when you expect a non-UI task to take a fairly long time to complete. An `Activity` that does not remain in the foreground can in all probability be terminated by the OS, while a `Service` can continue to run indefinitely.

A `Service` is created in a separate process when you don't want the garbage collector to affect its working. The garbage collector will, in that case, affect only the application process. Moreover, a `Service` in a separate process has the added advantage that it will consume slightly less memory than what it would if it were in the main application process.

The `Service` that you declare in a separate process can be either private to the application:

```
<service android:process=":my_private_process"
```

or it can be global:

```
<service android:process="my_global_process"
```

In the latter case there is no colon prefix. A `Service` in a private process can only interact with your application, while a `Service` in a public process can deal with other applications as well. This is mainly when a `Service` should be used in a separate process: when you want your application to share data or functionality with other applications, and to do it in the background without being disturbed by the OS or the GC. To quote the documentation:

`This allows components in different applications to share a process, reducing resource usage.`

Comment: your answer is specific to the `Service`, can you explain about other components.

Comment: The truth is, typical Android app developers rarely if ever use the `android:process` tag. This tag is used by native Android classes deep in the AOSP. Global processes at the application level are neither well documented nor widely used in practice. In fact, that`s why I've only written about `Service`. I never even heard of `Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver` or `ContentProvider` being used in a separate private process, leave alone a separate global process. My advice to you is not go too deep into this as you will practically never need to use it.